# Passing filewriter as a parameter?

Tags: java, filewriter

Im trying to write a file with filestream, but I cant understand how to pass a filewriter as a parameter to a function, here is my code

```
public static void main(String [] Args) throws IOException{
     try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Credits.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        graphColoring(0);//comienza en el primer vertice 



        if (Sol == false)
            pw.println("Existe solucion: Falso");
        else
            pw.println("Existe solucion: Verdadero");

        pw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("error");
    }
 }

public static void graphColoring(int k) 
{

    while(true){
        grNextValue(k);
        z=0;
        if(countDomain[k] == 0)
            return;//no es posible asignar un nuevo color
        if(k == limitVariables)
        {
            System.out.println("Existe solucion: Verdadero");
            tope = 1;
            for(int i=1; i<=k;i++,z++){
                int num = countDomain[i]-1;
                System.out.println(""+values[z]+" = "+domain[num]+" ");//todos los vertices son coloreados y asigna diferente color a cada uno


            }
            System.out.println();
            Sol = true;
        }
        else{
            graphColoring(k+1);//elige el siguiente vertice
        }
        tope = 1;

    }

}
```

Right now my code shows in console a list of solutions with

```
System.out.println(""+values[z]+" = "+domain[num]+" ")
```

I want this loop to be written in a text but I cant figure out how to do so, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question one solution would be to pass the `FileWriter` to your method (or make a static field for it). Something like,

```
public static void graphColoring(int k, FileWriter fw) 
{
    while(true){
        grNextValue(k);
        z=0;
        if(countDomain[k] == 0)
            return;
        if(k == limitVariables)
        {
            fw.append("Existe solucion: Verdadero");
            fw.append(System.lineSeparator());
            tope = 1;
            for(int i=1; i<=k;i++,z++){
                int num = countDomain[i]-1;
                fw.append(""+values[z]+" = "+domain[num]+" ");
                fw.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            fw.append(System.lineSeparator());
            Sol = true;
        }
        else{
            graphColoring(k+1);
        }
        tope = 1;
    }
}
```